# JSTL - How to reset a `ModelAttribute` without hitting the server?

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have a view `Search.jsp` that has a `form:form` that is connected to a `ModelAttribute`. I want to have a "Reset" Button in my view that will reset the Search Form.

I'm currently doing it using a simple link to reload the page, but that sends a new request to the server. Is there a way I can do this in JSTL, without hitting the server i.e. client-side?

A reset button doesn't work, since values are bound to the `@ModelAttribute` (unless the page has been freshly loaded)

Comment: What is the scope of the search bean?

Comment: modelattributes are server-side. u cannot refresh them from the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JSTL are **server side**. You need to do it with javascript.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is nice. Something like

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('');
```

Comment: Ok, I was starting to suspect that was the answer :D. Thanks.

Comment: jstl is have nothing to do with anything in client side. that we have to do using javascript etc.